# Problemas para agregar datos por get a consulta API en PHP

Tags: php, api

Estoy teniendo problemas para poder lograr que una API me devuelva la respuesta en base a parámetros de búsqueda ingresados por el usuario. He logrado que me devuelva el listado general (en Json) e imprimirlo, consumiendo solo los datos que considero relevantes. Sin embargo no logro que me devuelva solo aquellos datos que concuerdan con la búsqueda ingresada por el usuario.

Les dejo el código para ver si pueden echarme una mano y desde ya muchas gracias.

```
<?php
 $opciones = $_GET['opciones'];
 $postData = http_build_query(array(
  'q' => $opciones
  ));
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'header'=>"x-access-token: <My access token>",
    'content'=> $postData
    ));

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$resp = file_get_contents('https://affiliate.tutellus.com/api/v1/courses/', 
false, $context);
$json_response = json_decode($resp, true);  
//var_dump($json_response);
foreach ($json_response as $course) {
   #$imagen = $course["image_url"];
   echo $course["name"], "<br>";
   #echo '<img src="' . $imagen .'" />';
   echo $course["description"], "<br>";
   echo $course["url"], "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Qué pasa si haces `var_dump($postData);`?

Comment: Estoy pensando que a lo mejor no tienes que poner $postData como `content` sino concatenarlo a la url, algo como: `https://affiliate.tutellus.com/api/v1/courses?q=texto`

Comment: y porque no haces la petición con curl?

Comment: La [documentación de la API](https://affiliate.tutellus.com/docs) deja mucho que desear. Son ellos quienes deberían explicar claramente, a través de ejemplos, cómo habría que consultarla. Lo único que dan es una información muy vaga, en una *info bullet*, cuando te colocas sobre el signo de `?` donde dice *Query parameters*. Si eres usuario de la API deberías sugerirles que sean más explícitos en la documentación. Parece que hay que poner al final de la URL los parámetros, algo como `https://affiliate.tutellus.com/api/v1/courses/items?id=1`. No explican cómo se usa el parámetro `q` y etc.

Comment: Hola a todos. Agradezco infinitamente la ayuda que me han brindado. Voy a responder a todas vuestras preguntas:

Comment: En cuanto a que pasa con var_dump($potData); devuelve los parámetros correctamente. En cuanto a la solución definitiva estaba por el lado de lo que acotan amenadiel (en su segundo comentario) y A.Cedano. Era tal cual el ejemplo que plantean ambos. En cuanto a la documentación de la API coincido en que es demasiado exigua y vaga lo que no facilita las cosas. Carlos Quintero la opción con curl la exploré con resultados desastrosos. Reitero mi agradecimiento. Tema solucionado.